# How to render different Pages(Strapi Collection) on same Angular Component with help of navigation menu?

Tags: angular, typescript, strapi

I have created collection in Strapi called Pages i want to render them in a same component using my Navigation Bar Component but i don't know how to accomplish it.

What I'm actually getting is all the data from Collection displayed like this.
[image]

My question is how to render specific Page using navigation bar like seen above ,when i click "Ratenrechner" it should only show the "Ratenrechner".

The purpose of rendering it in a same component is because all of this pages have the same structure.

I will post my components and services code. Please let me know if u need more information or code to help me with this Problem. I'll try to keep it short and provide all the information needed.

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'page',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'page',
    component: PageComponent,
  }
];
```

page.service.ts

```
export class PageService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllPages(): Observable<Page> {
    return this.http.get<Page>(`${environment.apiUrl}/pages`).pipe(map(res => res));
  }

  getPage(pageID: any):Observable<Page> {
    return this.http.get<Page>(`${environment.apiUrl}/pages/${pageID}`).pipe(map(res => res));
  }
```

page.component.ts

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  pages?: Page;

  constructor(private pageSvc: PageService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getPages();
  }

  getPages() {
    this.pageSvc.getAllPages().subscribe(res => {
      this.pages = res;
    })
  }
}
```

page.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="pages">
  <div *ngFor="let pageData of pages.data">
    <h1>{{pageData.id}} - {{pageData.attributes.title}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

My navigation bar is also created with Strapi its a Content Type including Collection for dropdown menu and Component for a links;

navigation-bar.service

```
export class NavigationBarService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  // function to get all data response from top-left-menu in strapi
  getAllNavbarComponents(): Observable<Navbar> {
    return this.http.get<Navbar>(`${environment.apiUrl}/top-left-menu?[populate]=*`).pipe(map(res => res));
  }
}
```

navigation-bar-dropdown.service.ts

```
export class NavigationBarDropdownService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllDropdownComponents(): Observable<Dropdown> {
    return this.http.get<Dropdown>(`${environment.apiUrl}/sections?[populate]=*`).pipe(map(res => res));
  }

}
```

navigation-bar.component.ts

```
export class NavigationBarComponent implements OnInit {

  components?: Navbar;
  dropdownComponents?: Dropdown;

  constructor(private navbarSvc: NavigationBarService, private dropdownSvc: NavigationBarDropdownService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNavbarComponents();
    this.getDropdownComponents();
  }

  getNavbarComponents() {
    this.navbarSvc.getAllNavbarComponents().subscribe(res => {
      this.components = res;
    })
  }

  getDropdownComponents() {
    this.dropdownSvc.getAllDropdownComponents().subscribe(res => {
      this.dropdownComponents = res;
    })
  }

}
```

navigation-bar.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="components">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-expanded="false">
              Ratgeber
            </a>
            <ng-container *ngIf="dropdownComponents">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <div class="row row-cols-auto">

                  <div class="col" *ngFor="let dropdownComponents of dropdownComponents.data">
                    <!--            SECTION LABEL-->
                    <li
                      class="text-center my-2 fw-bold"
                    >
                      {{dropdownComponents.attributes.label}}
                    </li>
                    <!--            SECTION LINKS-->
                    <li
                      *ngFor="let links of dropdownComponents.attributes.links"
                    >
                      <a href="{{links.url}}">{{links.label}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </ng-container>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let sectionComponents  of components.data.attributes.body">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{sectionComponents.url}}">{{sectionComponents.label}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna post an answer to my Problem, maybe someone will encounter the same problem in a future. I'm not sure it is a correct way but it's working for now.

This video helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT3s9HQxc1c

Please let me know if someone have better solution to this problem.

I used ActivatedRoute to get my current url and i've wrote a function to GET one page by ID and I'm giving   my ID from current Route as param to my function.

page.component.ts

```
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {
  page?: Page;
  pageID?:  {id: number;};
  constructor(private pageSvc: PageService,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.pageID =  {
    id: this.route.snapshot.params['id']
  }
    this.getSpecificPage(this.pageID.id);
    // this.getPages();
  }

  // getPages() {
  //   this.pageSvc.getAllPages().subscribe(res => {
  //     this.pages = res;
  //   })
  // }

  getSpecificPage(id: any) {
    return this.pageSvc.getPage(id).subscribe( res => {
      this.page = res;
      console.log(this.page)
    })
  }
}
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'pages',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'pages/:id',
    component: PageComponent,
  }
];
```